# ASP.NET Grid View not updating inside an update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, aspxgridview

**Background:**
Trying to avoid the complete post back and use partial post back to refresh the data grid. I have checked MSDN, and stack overflow and tried different combinations of the control values for triggering the post back but no luck.

**Code**

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTest" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server" Visible="true" ShowHeader="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <Columns>
                         <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <div>Document Type</div>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="txtDescription" Style="margin: 2px" MaxLength="254" Text='<%# Bind("DocName") %>' runat="server" Width="200px" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <br />
                <label>
                    <AjaxControlToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" Width="400px" runat="server"
                        OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" />
                </label>
                <label id="lblStatus"></label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

**Code behind**

```
 if (AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string strPath = MapPath("~/Uploads/") + Path.GetFileName(e.filename);
        AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(strPath);
        SetGridData(1);
        upTest.Update();
    }

    private void SetGridData(int count)
{
    List<Document> Documents = new List<Document>();
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.DocName = "test doc";
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Documents.Add(doc);
    }
    gvTest.DataSource = Documents;
    gvTest.DataBind();
}
```

On Page_Load the Grid is loaded with 5 data rows and on the async post back the grid is reset to one data row. While looking at the chrome debugger, I can see the grid data is coming from the server on both Page_Load (5 rows) and async load( 1 data row). But the data grid is not refreshed. I do call the grid.DataBind() during the async post back. Anyone has any ideas whats going on? Am I missing something?

**Note: Everything works with normal ASP.Net controls, just dont work with AJAX file upload control**

Comment: I do call the Databind on async postback, yes I tried to set the update mode to 'always' and set the async postback trigger property. In the above code that I shared I am not using that approach. But I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling the `DataBind()` method of your `GridView` within `SetGridData`? And also add a `AsyncPostBackTrigger`

Have a look at an example [here](https://pawanmishra.wordpress.com/2009/10/03/ajaxcontroltoolkits-asyncfileupload-control/)

Answer (score 0):

try UpdateMode="Always" . it will work

Comment: Strangely not with the ajax asyncfileupload control in the update panel. Update panel works fine with normal asp controls.